# php variables - unexpected results

Tags: php

I am just learning about php and i cant understand why i get different results from the two following code snippets.

Snippet 1:

```
<?php
    $x = 22;
    $y = 12;
    $counter = 0;

    function add()
    {
        if ($GLOBALS['counter'] == 0) 
        {
            $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['z'] += $GLOBALS['y'];
        }
        $GLOBALS['counter'] ++;
    }

    add();
    echo "$z <br>";
    add();
    echo "$z <br>";
?>
```

the first returns 34 , 46 as expected.

Snippet 2:

```
<?php
    $x = 22;
    $y = 12;
    $counter = 0;

    function add()
    {
        if ($GLOBALS['counter'] == 0) 
        {
            $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['z'] += $GLOBALS['y'];
        }
        $GLOBALS['counter'] ++;
    }

    for ($x=0; $x < 2; $x++) 
    { 
        add();
        echo "$z <br>";
    }
?>
```

The second returns 12 , 24.

This may sound very simple but i can honestly not work out why this isn't working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your logic, shouldn't you be using `for ($counter=0; $counter < 2; $counter++)` since, you're setting x to be 0, you're going to get 12 and 24 returned

Comment: You are reseting `$x` to another value in your `for` loop. Try to AVOID using globals though: they're difficult to debug, hinder testing, and are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

You are reusing the variable name `$x` for your loop counter. You're setting `$x` to `0`, so you get `0 + 12` when you do `$_GLOBALS['x'] + $_GLOBALS['y']`. You must rename it to something you're not already using. I recommend changing it to `$i`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) 
{ 
    add();
    echo "$z <br>";
}
```

I also recommend that you avoid using `$_GLOBALS` in general.

Comment: I cant believe I didn't notice that! thanks a lot for everyone's responses.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a loop

```
for ($x=0; $x < 2; $x++) 
{ 
    add();
    echo "$z <br>";
}
```

You overwrite the definition of `x` from earlier... Change it to

```
for ($q=0; $q < 2; $q++) 
{ 
    add();
    echo "$z <br>";
}
```

and you'll see...